# Extension for arbitrary vectors

Tags: c#

Assume we have some structs (or classes):

```
public struct X
{
    //...
    public static X Add(X a, X b)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public struct Y
{
    //...
    public static Y Add(Y a, Y b)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create somewhere somehow a single method like:

```
public static T AddTwo(T a, T b)
{
    return Add(Add(a, b), b);
}
```

where T can be X, Y or others and **T must be the same throughout** a call to such method?
Preferably without casts all the way down.

---

On solutions that i tried:

1. Generics:

A simple mechanism like:

```
public static class AbstractVectorProcessor<T>
{
    public static T Add(T a, T b)
    {
        return T.Add(a, b);
    } 
}
```

is impossible to my knowledge as there is no way to tell this class that `T` implements `T Add(T a, T b)`.

2. Interfaces:

If you implement an interface like

```
interface I
{
    I Add(I a, I b);
}
//...
public struct X : I
//...
public struct Y : I
//...
```

then the result of "`X.Add(new X(), new X())`" will be of type `I` and not `X`. Moreover there is no problem with calling "`X.Add(new Y(), new Y())`".

Comment: What do you mean by `T must be the same throughout`?  That's how generics work.  T doesn't vary in the middle of a generic function.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Your function `AddTwo` would have to be inside a struct or class that defined an `Add` function or the code wouldn't compile. As it is, which `Add` method would be used?

Comment: If you implement an interface for example with" `I Add(I a, I b)`", "`X : I`" and "`Y : I`" then  the result of "`X.Add(new X(), new X())`" will be of type `I` and not `X`. Moreover there is no problem with calling "`X.Add(new Y(), new Y())`". @Amy

Comment: @HereticMonkey, obviously, but the idea is to implement it once and not for every X, Y, etc individually.

Comment: I make no assumptions about what is obvious and what is not. I think it's obvious that "T must be the same throughout" and that there should be a problem with calling `X.Add(new Y(), new Y())` since `X.Add` is defined as taking two `X`s.

Comment: If X and Y have the same structure, you may use generics to create a single strict. If not, you would somehow have to call T.Add which is not possible without having both X and Y implement a common interface I and having T declared to implement I.

Comment: @HereticMonkey did i not say **if** "`X : I`" and "`interface I { I Add(I a, I b); }`".

Comment: Not in your now-deleted comment.

Comment: "then the result of "X.Add(new X(), new X())" will be of type I and not X" - Incorrect, the type will be whatever type the method on X returns, however you will have to downcast back to that before using it as such. If you know you started with X though (which you do due to the 'T must be the same throughout'), then this is easy enough to do

Comment: Beware with structs implementing interfaces. If you do `I Add(I a, I b);` like in your interface `I` it will be boxed and you'll loose what you gained with struct. Actually it is advised to use struct sparingly, as you can shoot yourself in the foot with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your end goal is, but I think this will point you in the right direction possibly.

You can't specify static members on interfaces, so the interface `IAdd<T>` defines a single method `T Add(T b)` where it assumes that you have an item of type `T` already and you want to add another of the same type to it. For instance if you have a struct `xInstance` of type `X` and you want to add a different `X` you would call `xInstance.Add(anotherInstanceOfX);`

Now that you have an interface defined you can make a generic `AbstractVectorProcessor` that has a generic method `public static T Add<T>(T a, T b) where T : IAdd<T>`

You can use type inference to specify the type, so rewriting the example from before it would be `AbstractVectorProcessor.Add(xInstance, anotherInstanceOfX)`

At this point, though, I'm not sure what value the `AbstractVectorProcessor` would be when you can just as easily call `xInstance.Add(anotherInstanceOfX)`.

*Edit:*
I read the question again and realized you were looking for an abstract implementation of `AddTwo`, so I changed the `AbstractVectorProcessor` to implement an `AddTwo` where `b` is added twice.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = new X(10);
        var tripleX= AbstractVectorProcessor.AddTwo(x, x);
        Console.WriteLine(tripleX.Value);
    }

    public interface IAdd<T>
    {
        T Add(T b);
    }

    public struct X : IAdd<X>
    {
        public X(double val)
        {
            Value = val;
        }

        public double Value {get;}

        public X Add(X b)
        {
            return new X(Value + b.Value);
        }
    }

    public struct Y : IAdd<Y>
    {
        public Y(double val)
        {
            Value = val;
        }

        public double Value {get;}

        public Y Add(Y b)
        {
            return new Y(Value + b.Value);
        }
    }

    public static class AbstractVectorProcessor
    {
        public static T AddTwo<T>(T a, T b) where T : IAdd<T>
        {
            return a.Add(b).Add(b); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Returned `T` will be boxed if you use it through `AbstractVectorProcessor` so X and Y might as well be classes, but besides it it seems good :)

Comment: It works! _Your_ time machine works! Although `X : IAdd<X>` looks pretty silly. Also doesn't it make `Y : IAdd<X>` possible? But this might actually be a useful at some point...